SharePoint Migration tool - SharePoint to SharePoint (Files)
I have a small to mid size project i'm working on and i require a tool to move files between sharepoint sites.
I love te SPMT tool from MS but it does do SharePoint to SharePoint.
Is there any tool you can propose that won't break the clients bank? I love ShareGate but the price is a bit too high for the considering they only need it for files etc..
Thanks in Advance
